# How can I move my family to Lakeview Manor?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I decided to build a homestead, so I bought the land from the Jarl of Falkreath.  I build the small house, west wing, and haven't finished the library. I have one adopted kid (Sophie) and a husband (Marcurio).  At first, it was only me and Sophie, and when I tried to bring up the dialogue to move, it didn't show "Lakeview Manor" as an option (I only have the house in Whiterun, which I'm living in, and Lakeview Manor).  I read that it could fix it to marry someone, so I married Marcurio.  When we got married, it only had the Whiterun house as an option, and now the dialogue to move won't show for either.  I would really rather live in Lakeview Manor, as I've spent a ton of time on building it.  I don't want to restart from before I built it. Are there any fixes to this annoying bug?

I am playing on the PC. I already tried to "resurrect" Sophie so her package reset, it didn't work and now it won't even show the moving dialogue

Comment: How many beds do you have?

Comment: @Ben I have 3. 2 children because I was planning on adopting another later on, and another double bed for my husb and I. Both child's beds have chests.

Answer (score 3):

There are a multitude of bugs that could cause this, unfortunately. Hence I'd recommend fixing this with a mod that overrides the ai package.

1. [Custom Family Home](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/47621/?), 1148 endorsements
2. [Hearthfire Bugfix](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/25795/?), 271 endorsements

You may know this already, but it bears repeating: Try out the mods first on a test save that you can throw away. This way you can remove them if you don't like them. Uninstalling mods in Skyrim often leaves scripts running in your savegame that can cause instability or bloat in the future.

If you dont want to install a mod, possible hotfixes [from this thread](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:231399) include:

1. Sleeping in Lakeview for 12 hours, then asking your spouse to move in
2. Ensure you have the [adoption prerequisites](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Adoption#Prerequisites) for the house.

Off-topic, I strongly recommend getting the [Lakeview Manor Extended](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/31380/?) mod. Not only does it get rid of the disgusting necromancer altar and skeletons on your front porch, it also significantly upgrades your house.